# MySQL editable sort index in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a way to sort elements in a list based on the order they were added from oldest to newest. This would be easy to do in MySQL using an ORDER BY on a created DATETIME. The problem is I then want to be able to move elements up and down the list and have that order saved in the database, but also make sure that new elements get put on the end of the list.

I have thought of using an INT index and just increment that for each new item that is added to the list. Then when an existing item is moved up or down in the list, swap the index numbers. Does this sound like the best way to achieve this result? If not, would anyone be able to provide some insight of a better way. Thanks

Comment: Drag drop sort tutorials should cover this

Comment: See stuff like http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2011/11/cakephp-ajax-sortable-list-with-updates/

Comment: Alright, looks like this was the way I was thinking of doing it in MySQL and in PHP. If somebody would like to create an answer with more details, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving this by using an INT field in the MySQL table called `order`. When new items are added, the order field is just incremented from the previous largest order in the table. When items are moved up or down in order, all other items orders are shifted up or down accordingly so that the order numbers are always continuous. On delete, orders are also shifted down.